Deleting bumped topics
Topics may be "bumped" to the top of the Active view.

What can cause a question to be bumped?
The Community user will bump non-negatively scored, open questions every hour that have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that.

For example:



I propose to delete (or propose we delete) these, on this Meta site:

They clutter the top of the Active view
They're mostly uninteresting -- answered but nobody thought the answer worth upvoting

When they're deleted you'll see a log of the human activity on this site, not only the bot named "Community".
